# How to change the icon color of a NavigationView when it is collapsed in Android Studio Programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, navigationview

[image]

Hi, I need to change the color of the NavigationView icon when it is collapsed, as you can see in the upper left corner it is white and I would need to change it dynamically according to a user configuration (for example: Orange).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **`MaterialToolbar`** you can use the method **`setNavigationIconColor`**:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.xxxx))
```

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha03`**.

If you are using a lower version or an `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` you can use:

```
val wrappedNavigationIcon = DrawableCompat.wrap(toolbar.navigationIcon!!)
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedNavigationIcon, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.xxxx))
```

or in java:

```
   Drawable wrappedNavigationIcon = DrawableCompat.wrap(toolbar-getNavigationIcon());
   DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedNavigationIcon, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.xxxx));
```

Comment: Hi, the second option you mentioned does not work for me.
Could you tell me how to use MaterialToolbar?

Comment: This solution works, but when the fragment changes, the modification does not last.
Could someone tell me where to put the code of the MaterialToolbar?